# How to become a function to a property when I use laravel and october cms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

**Eloquent: Relationships in laravel:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**Database Relationships in october cms**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public $hasMany = [
        'comments' => 'Acme\Blog\Models\Comment'
    ];
}
```

I want to know what has october cms done? The function become a property !

Comment: Functions or methods can't be a property.

Comment: It seems like October is pulling all the comments for a post by default and storing them in a property.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting part is  "extends Model"

you can see in october CMS models are extending from its own library.

so ultimately in their library they are reading this property and convert it in to relations.

they use magic methods to intercept relation methods calls.

in short they have wrapped laravel model with their own so they can add additional features.